# Как можно с анимировать смену курсора при наведении cursor: url()?

Tags: javascript, css

При наведении на элемент должен плавно менятся курсор, написал такой код для смены курсора:

```
.element{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #333;
  cursor:url(курсор_1);
}
.element:hover{
  cursor:url(курсор_2);
}
```

И здесь курсор меняется, но вот меняется он всегда моментально и нельзя сделать плавный переход от курсора 1 к курсору 2.

Как можно с анимировать плавную смену курсора в данном случае на js или на css?

Comment: Скриншот курсора можно? Я понял вашу идею, но тут вешается элемент и JS перемещается по экрану эмитирую курсор, и уже его можно будет анимировать. Побольше подробностей бы

Comment: в частности хочу менять курсор иконки "arrow-left-circle" на "arrow-right-circle", есть ещё несколько идей но то второстепенно. Ресурс с иконками - https://feathericons.com/

Comment: Лично я скачивал размером в 45 пиксель каждую, но можете использовать любой курсор по вашему желанию, мне интересно понять идею

Answer (score 1):

Можно изобразить что-то такое:

```js
let arrow = i => `<svg 
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
  xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' 
  width='32px' 
  height='32px' 
  viewBox='-26 -26 52 52'>
  
    <path 
      transform='rotate(${i/100*180-90})' 
      d='M0,15v-30l-10,10M0,15v-30l10,10' 
      stroke='black' 
      fill='none' 
      stroke-width='5' 
      stroke-linejoin='round' />
          
    <circle 
      r='23' 
      stroke='black' 
      fill='none' 
      stroke-width='5' />
      
</svg>`;

document.head.innerHTML += `<style>
  @keyframes cur {${Array(101).fill(0).map((_, i) => `${i}% {
    cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(arrow(i))}") 16 16, pointer;
  }`).join('')}}
<style>
`;
```

```css
.left, .right {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background: wheat;
  float:left
}

.right:hover {
  animation: cur 500ms forwards;
}

.left:hover {
  animation: cur 500ms forwards reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!! Класс!

Answer (score 0):

На будущее: плавная анимация возможна только для свойств, у которых в принципе вычислимо промежуточное состояние. Например, цвет текста или фона, размеры, угол поворота.

Если промежуточных состояний быть не может, то и анимации не будет - например, для свойства display (а как бы вы представили промежуточное состояние между `display:none` и `display:block?`) или background-image (было `url('../my_img.jpg')`, стало `url('/images/new_file.png')`, что должно быть средним для этих двух значений?).

То же самое относится к свойству `cursor`.

Но можно попробовать обойти это, добавив МНОГО курсоров (например, десяток) и css-анимацию по кадрам на, скажем, полсекунды.